# Can a quadrupole form in a purely organic crystalline material?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, physical-chemistry, molecules, multipole-expansion

I'm a chemist so bear with me here. This is a question about small molecules, such as [biphenyls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biphenyl). In the solid-state biaromatic systems without steric hinderance forms planar conjugated structures. By choosing specific substituents it is possible to polarize such systems. In extreme cases, DFT calculations show, that there is almost no electron density at the one end of the molecule and all of it located at the other. As such, there is a linear polarization of this molecule having a δ(+) at one end and a δ(-) at the other end.
First of all, can such species be considered a dipole? If so what kind of a dipole is it?

Secondly, in the solid-state, there is a specific crystal lattice packing for most of such molecules where the δ(+)-δ(-) plane is located above a  δ(-)-δ(+) plane. Such packing is energetically favorable because of the through-space electrostatic interactions between δ(+) and δ(-) in adjacent molecules which minimizes local positive and negative charges. Simply put a polarized vector --> is put below another equal and opposite vector <--. To me it looks like a quadrupole, is this true?

Finally, such packing as discussed above produces unorthodox behavior of these molecules with respect to electronic transitions and light emission of excited states.

Answer (score 0):

First, your first question ("what kind of dipole is it?") is not clear for me.

Then, please correct me if I misunderstand you: we consider solid-state system which consists of biphenyl fragments with substituents?

In my view, the answer is simple. $\pi$-system has a quadrupole moment (at least in a certain approximation because multipole expansion consists all terms).This moment is briefly discussed in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cation%E2%80%93pi_interaction) article and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Molecular_Simulation/Quadrupole-Quadrupole_Interactions). Also, it seems useful to read about $\pi$-$\pi$ stacking, [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(chemistry)). Therefore, in my opinion (I considered quadrupole interactions in aromatic systems long time ago and my opinion may be not so authoritative) that your statement about quadrupoles is correct. Aromatic systems have quadrupole moment and it is possible to vary it by appropriate substituents. These molecules can form a crystal (for instance, liquid crystal) but it seems to be not so stable due to non-covalent nature of interaction. Also, different polymers wtih biphenyl base can form liquid crystals.

Finally, could you please provide more details about your last statement (about electronic transitions & light emissions)?

Comment: Hi, thank You for the answer, for clarification: Yes this is a solid state crystal, secondly the problem is, that regular cation-pi interactions are quite well known and studied, however, such polarized interactions between pi systems are not. Thirdly pi-pi interactions, at least in the terms of luminescence have been around forever and are very detrimental for photoluminescent properties of materials (generally discussed as aggregation caused quenching (ACQ)), however in our recent paper we found that highly polarized pi systems with an actual positive charge gives the opposite effect

Comment: As such the through space pi(+)-pi  interactions (between 2 planes) is in some way fundamentally different from regular pi-pi interactions. In chemistry we rationalize the detrimental effect of through space pi-pi interactions as the overlap of the pi orbitals in adjecent molecules, that lead to efficient energy transfer between these molecules or formation of excimers. Additionally it is shown in at least 1 example in the literature, that if specific crystal packing elongates the pi-pi interaction to the length these pi orbitals cannot overlap the detrimental effect on luminescence is negated

Comment: In contrast these pi(+)-pi interactions happen at various lengths, (in and outside of orbital overlap length) but the effect on all materials we have is the same -> a drastic increase in the solid state emission as compared to solution or amorphous matrix. Which points to the fact that these interactions are responsible for the high emission. As this kind of solid state interactions have not been explored, im trying to figure out what direction to go to in understanding these solid state effects. At this point it is clear to me that rationalization from the POV of org. chem. is not enough.